# MariaDB gives 150 error even though foreign key checks are disabled

Tags: mariadb, foreign-keys

I need to update a column in a mariaDB table from an `int` to a `bigint unsigned`. However, that column is the primary key of the table and is used as a foreign key by several other tables.

From reading around this problem, I expected the following to work:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
ALTER TABLE my_main_table MODIFY COLUMN the_main_column BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE other_table_1 MODIFY COLUMN the_ref_column BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE other_table_2 MODIFY COLUMN the_ref_column BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
<etc>
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

But instead each `ALTER TABLE` command gets an error of the form:

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './myDB/#sql-ae8_7acfa78' to './myDB/my_main_table' (errno: 150)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and how I can make this work?
The only alternative I can see is to go through each child table, drop the foreign key, then do the `MODIFY` statements and then go back through and remake the foreign keys, but this is a rather arduous task and seems to me like it should not be necessary.

This is MariaDB 5.5.68 (on centOS 7)

Comment: In MariaDB the variable `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` can have SESSION scope. Setting it to disabled state does not effect the server itself, and your ALTER TABLE fails due to global flag state which is enabled. Try to disable this setting globally then perform your action. But I recommend you do not manipulate with FK checks but simply drop FK constraint, alter tables then recreate FK.

Comment: [MariaDB 5.5 RIP!](https://mariadb.org/mariadb-55-rip/)

Comment: @Akina OK, thanks - I guess I'll bite the bullet and do it the slow way :)

Comment: @hobby_programmer yeah, I know, and we're going to have to upgrade from Centos 7 very soon. But it's going to be hell.